# GXT grid button selects row

Tags: button, grid, gxt

I have a grid where a button on each row deletes the row upon clicking (with a confirmation), but when the button is clicked, the row is also selected, performing the actions in onRowClick(..) method together.

How can I have the button such that clicking it does not results in selecting the row item?

Answer (score 0):

The click handler for your button should call `DomEvent.stopEvent`. The doc (2.2.4) is here: http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/#com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.event.DomEvent-stopEvent%5B0%5D

Comment: I'm using sencha gxt, not extjs

Comment: @Katie, Yes, the link above is for GXT, not their javascript lib. You will notice that they have extjs in all their package names.

Comment: I'm using com.sencha.gxt. There's no such class and method in there

Comment: @Kathie...whatever you say. If you click the link in my original comment it will take you to the gxt docs where that class is documented, but maybe you're on a different verseion?

Comment: Ya. I finally realised you are referring to gxt 2.0 while I'm on 3.0 =/